# Replace values in a string without looping thru each row

Tags: javascript, performance

I have this output string:

```
"ABC",1,"123 Corner St","N"
"ABC",1,"333 Brick Ave","N"
```

I need to replace all "ABC" with YYY excluding quotes. Also remove double quotes in the last field to N. Here's resulting output should be:

```
YYY,1,"123 Corner St",N
YYY,1,"333 Brick Ave",N
```

How to achieve this without having to iterate thru each row of string output? Also only with vanilla JavaScript preferably in old version.

Comment: I don't personally like to work with them but this sounds like [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using string replace with regex:

```js
const str1 = '"ABC",1,"123 Corner St","N"'
const str2 = '"ABC",1,"333 Brick Ave","N"'

console.log(str1.replace(/"ABC",(.*),"N"/, "YYY,$1,N"))
console.log(str2.replace(/"ABC",(.*),"N"/, "YYY,$1,N"))
```

Comment: Or if it's a multiline text you can use `str.replace(/^"ABC",(.*),"N"$/mg, "YYY,$1,N")`

Comment: yes this would work for this exact specific output. But i might have output with many fields/columns per row and I might have to replace certain fields, not only 1st and last

Comment: Well, you didn't mention that.. In that case, you can create a regex with as many matching groups as you need.